# is there a built in way to handle tolerance in constraints

Tags: pyomo

Is there a built-in way to handle relative and absolute tolerances in pyomo when building constraints rather than managing it manually?

a <= b

a == b

a >= b

When a and b are real numbers, there obviously has to be some notion of what is close enough.  Python has isclose() which allows absolute and relative tolerances.  How does pyomo handle it, or is it passed on to the solvers to manage the tolerances?

Comment: The solvers manage constraint tolerances.